# How to get 'bold attribute' only on clicked item

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I have a question and I need some help. Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).className = 'show_team';
}
```

```css
.show_team {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a id="1" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 1</a>
<a id="2" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 2</a>
<a id="3" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 3</a>
<a id="4" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 4</a>
<a id="5" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 5</a>
<a id="6" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 6</a>
<a id="7" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 7</a>
<a id="8" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 8</a>
<a id="9" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 9</a>
<a id="10" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 10</a>
```

I want to display link text in bold only the item that is last clicked. But I can't, because when I click one, other links remains bold too.

Comment: If my solution works for you, please upvote and mark it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `.show_team` should be removed from all elements when clicked then added to the clicked element only.

I have updated the code, you don't need to add `onclick` function on every element anymore.

```js
(function() {
  var aList = document.getElementsByClassName("link"); // list of elements
  for(var i = 0; i < aList.length; i++) {
    aList[i].addEventListener("click", function(element) {
      for(var i = 0; i < aList.length; i++) {   // loop through elements
        aList[i].classList.remove("show_team"); // and remove the class "show_team"
      }
      // add class "show_team" to the clicked element
      element.target.classList.add("show_team");
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
.show_team {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a id="1" class="link" href="#">Team 1</a>
<a id="2" class="link" href="#">Team 2</a>
<a id="3" class="link" href="#">Team 3</a>
<a id="4" class="link" href="#">Team 4</a>
<a id="5" class="link" href="#">Team 5</a>
<a id="6" class="link" href="#">Team 6</a>
<a id="7" class="link" href="#">Team 7</a>
<a id="8" class="link" href="#">Team 8</a>
<a id="9" class="link" href="#">Team 9</a>
<a id="10" class="link" href="#">Team 10</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the css class for the element that is previously shown bold

code sample to get all html element with class 'show_team'

```
document.getElementsByClassName('show_team')
```

it will return an array of elements, so you can reset class with following sample

```
document.getElementsByClassName('show_team')[0].className = ''
```

This is sample with assumption that 'show_team' will be used for one element at a time and to give you a idea about.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following code to your onClick function before setting class:

```
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            document.getElementById(i.toString()).className = '';
            //alert("test");
        }
```

Here is complete workout:

```js
     function myFunction(id){
      for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
       document.getElementById(i.toString()).className = '';
       //alert("test");
      }
      document.getElementById(id).className = 'show_team';
     }
```

```css
 .show_team{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: green;
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <a id="1" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 1</a>
 <a id="2" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 2</a>
 <a id="3" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 3</a>
 <a id="4" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 4</a>
 <a id="5" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 5</a>
 <a id="6" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 6</a>
 <a id="7" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 7</a>
 <a id="8" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 8</a>
 <a id="9" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 9</a>
 <a id="10" href="#" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">Team 10</a>
</body>
```